# Establecer condición después de pulsar editar cita en sweet alert 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert2

estoy utilizando sweet alert 2 y me pasa que después de pulsar el botón de "editar cita" o la "x" para cerrar la alerta no me redirija siempre a editar cita, solo cuando pulso dicho botón de "editar cita" y cuando pulso la "x" me cierre la alerta. Supongo que para esto debo establecer una condición dentro del "then((result)" o lo que viene siendo un if, pero no se me ocurre la manera a ver si alguien sabe como hacerlo. Gracias.

```
await Swal.fire({
    title: "Incidencia con cita",
    text: "Se ha encontrado un registro con cita, nº de incidencia: '.$temp[0]['fk_incidencia'].'",
    icon: "info",
    confirmButtonColor: "#2b77c0",
    confirmButtonText: "Editar cita",
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    showCloseButton: true,
    }).then((result) => {  
        window.open("_mis_incidencias.php?opciones_cita=editar_cita&fecha_inicio='.$temp[0]['fecha_inicio'].'&fecha_fin='.$temp[0]['fecha_fin'].'&id_incidencia='.$Incidencia->get_Id().'&fk_incidencia='.$temp[0]['fk_incidencia'].'&descripcion_cita='.$temp[0]['descripcion'].'&aviso='.$temp[0]['aviso'].'")
});
```

Comment: [Revisa la doc](https://sweetalert2.github.io). Dentro del `then` debes verificar si hubo confirmación o lo que sea y actuar en consecuencia. Este es un ejemplo de la misma doc: `Swal.fire({
  title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
  showDenyButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Save',
  denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
}).then((result) => {
  /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
  } else if (result.isDenied) {
    Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
  }
})`

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, solo me hacía falta saber result.isConfirmed ya que desconocía que si pulsabas el botón confirmar podías recoger ese valor. Me a funcionado bien gracias. Un saludo máquina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso, `result` debe ser verificado según el tipo de botón que has decidido mostrar, [tal y como indica la documentación](https://sweetalert2.github.io).

Para `confirmButton` debes verificar con `if (result.isConfirmed) {`

Por ejemplo:

```
await Swal.fire({
    title: "Incidencia con cita",
    text: "Se ha encontrado un registro con cita, nº de incidencia: '.$temp[0]['fk_incidencia'].'",
    icon: "info",
    confirmButtonColor: "#2b77c0",
    confirmButtonText: "Editar cita",
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    showCloseButton: true,
    }).then((result) => {
        if(result.isConfirmed) {  
            window.open("_mis_incidencias.php?opciones_cita=editar_cita&fecha_inicio='.$temp[0]['fecha_inicio'].'&fecha_fin='.$temp[0]['fecha_fin'].'&id_incidencia='.$Incidencia->get_Id().'&fk_incidencia='.$temp[0]['fk_incidencia'].'&descripcion_cita='.$temp[0]['descripcion'].'&aviso='.$temp[0]['aviso'].'")
    }
});
```

Aunque debo decir que es extraño que tu código termine en un `window.open` ¿? Es como caer en el vacío, dejando al usuario abandonado del lado del servidor. Todos esos asuntos son para integrar todo en la página actual. Revisa los ejemplos de la doc, hay varios ejemplos donde se hacen peticiones en cadena al servidor o cosas así, supongo que es eso lo que necesitas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba para que mi código funcionase. Y no sé como no lo e visto, está claramente en la documentación. Un saludo amigo.

Comment: @Ismael me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.